# OK to put comments before the XML declaration?

Tags: xml, xml-declaration

Is it OK to put comments before the XML declaration in an XML file?

```
<!--
Is this bad to do?
-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<someElement />
```

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: Hey! Don't call me out on my bad habit of asking first and experimenting later... ^_^

Comment: Experimenting would only allow you to say "well, it works on *my* computer", which isn't that helpful. Some XML processors may allow it, some may not. But if you follow the spec, then there's a greater chance that ALL XML processors (present and future) will be able to process your files.

Comment: anyway, guess it's clear that this is not allowed - for reason whysoever :D

and if your parser marks this as correct (which isn't good but possible), experimenting doesn't really help anyway....

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, it's not OK.

[Appendix F of the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-guessing) says:

> Because each XML entity not
>   accompanied by external encoding
>   information and not in UTF-8 or UTF-16
>   encoding must begin with an XML
>   encoding declaration, in which the
>   first characters must be '< ?xml', any
>   conforming processor can detect, after
>   two to four octets of input, which of
>   the following cases apply.

Ah, but, section F is non-normative, you say.

Well, [section 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-well-formed) gives the production for a well-formed XML document, thus:

```
[1]     document       ::=       prolog element Misc*
```

...and in [section 2.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-prolog-dtd) we get the production for "prolog":

```
[22]    prolog     ::=       XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?
[23]    XMLDecl    ::=      '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
```

So, you can *omit* the < ?xml declaration, but you can't prefix it with anything.

(Incidentally, "Misc" is the category that comments fall into).

Comment: Beautiful answer, great research exactly what I needed. +1.

Answer (score 7):

according to [this page](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/xmlinformation/ht/htcommentxml.htm), this is illegal:

> When adding reference comments to your XML code, remember that they cannot come at the very top of your document. In XML, only the XML declaration can come first:
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The XML declaration specifies the document encoding, which is as important for comments as for structural XML.  Therefore, the declaration should go first.  I wouldn't be surprised if many XML readers were able to deal with this, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: well, i agree with you. in fact the parser must have an idea how to read the document as he wouldn't be able to read the encoding neither. therefore only putting multi-byte characters into this comment should be disallowed...

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not comply with XML standards, but comments are good.